# Avoid implicit conversion from date to timestamp for selects with Oracle using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.7.GA criteria queries to select rows from an Oracle Enterprise Edition 10.2.0.4.0  database, filtering by a timestamp field. The field in question is of type `java.util.Date` in Java, and `DATE` in Oracle.

[It turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945603/why-is-oracle-so-slow-when-i-pass-a-java-sql-timestamp-for-a-date-column) that the field gets mapped to `java.sql.Timestamp`, and Oracle converts all rows to `TIMESTAMP` before comparing to the passed in value, [bypassing the index](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1001146&p=2427294#p2427294) and thereby ruining performance.

One solution would be to use Hibernate's `sqlRestriction()` along with Oracle's `TO_DATE` function. That would fix performance, but requires rewriting the application code (lots of queries).

So is there a more elegant solution? Since Hibernate already does type mapping, could it be configured to do the right thing?

**Update:** The problem occurs in a variety of configurations, but here's one specific example:

- Oracle Enterprise Edition 10.2.0.4.0
- Oracle JDBC Driver 11.1.0.7.0
- Hibernate 3.2.7.GA
- Hibernate's Oracle10gDialect
- Java 1.6.0_16

Comment: I think that this depends on the (version of the) driver you're using (see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1566 and the link you provided) and maybe the dialect. Please clarify both.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I clarified the question with specific versions.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound drastic, but when faced with this problem we ended up converting all DATE columns to TIMESTAMP types in the database.  There's no drawback to this that I can see, and if Hibernate is your primary application platform then you'll save yourself future aggravation.

Notes:

- The column types may be changed with
  a simple "ALTER tableName MODIFY
  columnName TIMESTAMP(precisionVal)".
- I was surprised to find that indexes 
  on these columns did NOT have to be
  rebuilt.

Again, this only makes sense if you're committed to Hibernate.

Comment: The downsize is that you more than double the space requirements. Date requires 8 bytes while timestamp takes 20 bytes.

Comment: Another downside is that a (DATE - DATE) results in a NUMBER datetype, but a (TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP) results in an INTERVAL datatype. So it is possible that such a 'simple' conversion will break existing logic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately, converting all DATE coulmns is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#08_01):

> "11.1 drivers by default convert SQL DATE to Timestamp when reading from the database"

So this is an expected behaviour.
To me this means that actual values coming from `DATE` columns are converted to `java.sql.Timestamp`, not that bind variables with `java.util.Date` are converted to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

An `EXPLAIN PLAN` output would help identifying the issue. Also, an Oracle trace could tell you exactly what type is assigned to the bind variable in the query.

If that's really happening it could be a Oracle bug.

You can work around it this way:

- Create an FBI ([Function Based Index](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref928)) on the `DATE` column, casting it to a `TIMESTAMP`. For example:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX tab_idx ON tab (CAST(date_col AS TIMESTAMP)) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
  ```
- Create a View that contains the same `CAST` expression. You can keep the same column name if you want:

  ```
  CREATE VIEW v AS
  SELECT CAST(date_col AS TIMESTAMP) AS date_col, col_1, ... FROM tab;
  ```
- Use the View instead of the Table (it's often a good idea anyway, e.g. if you were already using a View, you wouldn't need to change the code at all). When a `java.sql.Timestamp` variable will be used with `date_col` in the `WHERE` condition, (if enough selective) the Index will be used.
- If you find out why there was a `java.sql.Timestamp` (or Oracle fixes the potential bug), you can always go back just changing the View (and dropping the FBI), and it would be completely transparent to the code